# Can a person wield a fist-load weapon with their mouth?

Tags: martial-arts, hand-to-hand-combat

Like I’m imagining a push dagger that’s designed to deflect blows, sort of like if deer horn knives were kept between the teeth. Is this in anyway plausible?

Comment: What do you think? Imagine having a push dagger clenched in your teeth, and going up against someone with a push dagger clenched in their fist. There's an expectation that questions on this site show a certain level of research effort, and not just idly ask questions.

Comment: Hi Lynne! I think you have a kernel of a good worldbuilding question here. Unfortunately, you're in a bit of a pickle here: since it has gotten answers, you can't make any major edits that would invalidate those answers. And sometimes we have the bad habit of answering questions that obviously need work! I would like to suggest that you leave this question as is and work on an improved version which can post in our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). This is a place where new users can post their questions and get (cont)

Comment: (cont) some help with learning the skills required to write good questions. The better your questions are, the better our answers will be, and the better this community will be for future users! Just imagine: fifty years from now, some kid who's looking for a worldbuilding angle on mouth wielded fist weapons! How great would it be if she could stumble on your awesomely edited and much improved question!

Answer (score 2):

They could wield it, but it would be an ineffective weapon that was difficult to do any damage with in a fight. As it's not designed for the job, much like you don't wear a boot on your hand, you could, but it's suboptimal.

There are effective mouth operated weapons already that would be much more suitable.

If you want to deflect weapons from the area around your mouth, wear a closed helmet, don't try and swordfight the blows away with a knife between your teeth, you'll end up with shattered teeth at best.

Answer (score 1):

Boxeurs wear teeth protection to prevent damages caused by blows to their face, and so do many other sportsmen when face impacts are possible.

Teeth are optimized for chewing, thus handling compressive loads, not shear loads. If a punch can make some teeth come loose, even more can anything with an arm acting as multiplier which is held by a bite.